# Eclipse - Importing contents of managed package with same name of unmanaged package

Tags: managed-package, eclipse

We created an unmanaged package and installed it into another dev org.  From that other dev org, we created a managed package with the same name as the unmanaged package.  Now, I tried to install the package contents via the "Contents of Package" option and it is giving me error that there are duplicate package names.

So, I can't delete the unmanaged package since it will remove all the components from my managed package.  Is there any way to make the names unique, or has anyone experienced this before and have other solutions?

Comment: It's not possible to uninstall an unmanaged package without removing the components of that package. I'mm afraid that you may be out of luck here.